# Setting Value and Text of ComboBox Using Property Panel

Tags: vb.net, combobox, selectedtext

I have a combobox in my VB.NET application that is populated using the "Items" property in the property panel. The "Items" property will say "(Collection)" and when selected show a button with "..." This button expands to a new window where you can populate the items in the combobox. The text editor allows me to populate the list and looks like this:

```
Option 1
Option 2
Option etc...
```

The combobox populates properly, but when calling the SelectedText value of the combobox:

```
If ComboBox.SelectedText = "Option 1"
```

ComboBox.SelectedText is always an empty string (="")

I know I can populate the box in code and set the text and value members through code, but I am wondering why the selectedtext property is essentially blank when populated using the properties panel.

Comment: The SelectedItem property is pulling the selection out as a string... I always solve my problem right after posting the question.

Comment: SelectedText is returning the *highlighted* portion of the text box.

Comment: Not all properties are exposed to the property grid in the editor.